# Why Transparent BSDF blocks reflections of Principled BSDF? (Cycles)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, artifacts

I wanted to share an issue related to Cycles shaders I don't really know how to face.

I am rendering a honey pot. Nothing crazy about this. But when I tried to add the sticker I noticed some reflection artifacts.

I will try to explain it as simple as possible.

**Context**

The scene is rendered using Cycles on Blender 2.8.

I have a glass honey pot. This honey pot has another object inside that represents the honey (irrelevant).

The honey pot material uses just a Glass BSDF Shader.
[image: Nodes of Glass Honey Pot material]

Over the honey pot surface, there is a plane. This plane represents the sticker.

The sticker material mixes two shaders (a Principled BSDF and a Transparent BSDF) who are mixed dependently of the alpha of the sticker texture.
[image: Nodes of Sticker material]

**The problem**

Scene renders perfectly when the only element generating reflections is the HDRI skymap.
[image: Render with sticker]
[image]

If we add another object (like a white surface) to the scene, the transparent areas (Transparent BSDF) of the sticker do not reflect the white surface. Either Glass BSDF shader of the honey pot.
[image: With sticker]
[image: Without sticker]

My questions are:

- What is going on here?
- How can I avoid this artifact?

Thanks in advance!